# How to compare two text and identify which words are added and which are removed

Tags: c#, .net

I have `text1` and `text2`, now i want to compare `text1` and `text2` and identify differences with highlighted color by which word are removed and which are added and display in `text3`, Red color will be removed color and green color will be added color. 
I will display `text3` in WebBrowser control so `text3` display as htmlfile and look proper with color.

Example:

[image]

**Below is my code but i have some problems in it.**

1. In for loop `oldt.Length` is more `newt[i]` last index, so it gives error "Index was outside the bounds of the array."
2. From `oldText` last two word are removed "Category: javascript", but in my output result I want this two words in strike tag because this words are removed from `oldtext`.

```
string oldText = "Name: justin Parker Link: http://github.com/jparkerweb/htmldiff-example About: html diff poc Description: front-end lib to show what has changed between html blocks Category: javascript";
string newText = "Name: Justin Parker Link: http://github.com/jparkerweb/htmldiff-example About: HTML diff example Description: front-end lib to show differences between HTML blocks";
string result = "";

string[] oldt = oldText.Split(' ');
string[] newt = newText.Split(' ');

for (int i = 0; i < oldt.Length; i++)
{
     if (oldt[i] == newt[i])
     {
         result += oldt[i].ToString() + " ";
     }
     else
     {
         result += "<strike><font color='red'>" + oldt[i].ToString() + "</font></strike>" + "<u><font color='Green'>" + newt[i].ToString() + "</font></u>" + " ";
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us the code, what have you tried so far? No one here can give you a complete solution.

Comment: You are asking for something extremely specific, and is nearly asking for a library. Even if it wasnt, its asking for someone to write code for you that involves a lot of work. This is just way too broad

Answer (score 2):

Load both words of text1 and text2 to an array using **Split** and compare each array index for match. Do your logic on comparison while looping do determine if replaced, removed or added by moving to each index and checking the succeeding and preceding index values.

Good luck coding!!!